Is anything known about the center of the Fomin-Kirillov algebra?
Let $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m}$ be the quotient of the Fomin-Kirillov algebra so that its pairing becomes certainly nondegenerate. This algebra is conjecturally isomorphic to the Fomin-Kirillov algebra $\mathcal{E}_m$ - and known to be isomorphic for $m\leq 5$.
I would like to know if anything is known about the center of $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m}$. To answer, you may assume that $\dim(\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m})<\infty$, in which case I expect that
$$
Z(\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m})=\mathbf{k}1\oplus\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m}^\mathrm{top}\,.
$$
I'm also interested in what is known in the cases $m\leq 5$ where $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{S}_m}$ and $\mathcal{E}_m$ are known to be finite dimensional and isomorphic - and which might support my conjecture.
